# Regex, exclude certain character

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regular expression. However I get stuck and can't find the solution :(. Please help.

I want to get the string contains `{\d}` that are not preceed by `\`.

Example:

```
abc{1}def{2} ghi{3} jkl{4}{5}mno \{6}ofg\{7}{8}.
```

The result would be :

```
{1} {2} {3} {4} {5} and {8}.
```

Any idea to build regex for it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You use a caret after the left square bracket to negate a character class.

I.e. `[^\\](\{\d\})`

Comment: This will match the character before the { character too, which doesn't seem to be what Keeghi wants.

Comment: Right you are. Added a capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex:

```
(?<!\\)(\{\d\})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<!\\){\d}
```

This will match only the portions you want.